# Electroconductive fabric

Tags: usb, heat, electricity, fabric

Just by looking at the pictures, can anyone help me identify what kind of blanket the copper strips are glued to? The kind of material and composition.

Apparently seems to me to be a very thin glass blanket, but I'm not sure as I don't have any technical knowledge of fabrics.

I need a fabric that is electroconductive and causes the larger fabric to warm up where the blanket and the copper are glued together. This larger one is a TNT (textile non textile).

[image: Model]

Comment: It is not "too broad" at all. He wants to know what the material is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is called "tissue", "veil", or "mat", or "surface veil (credit to @wbeaty)" . It just refers to a light, unwoven fabric as opposed to something like glass fiber or carbon fiber which has long, continuous, aligned fibers. In composites manufacture, it is not used as for load bearing, but as an outer layer to hide texture.

It comes in different materials and if you need conduction, you might just use the carbon variety.

Comment: quick googling also turns up the term "surfacing veil"